# Javascript 'dynamic' form concatenating string onto form action

Tags: javascript

I have the following script constructing a form like so:

```
var sHTML = "";
sHTML += "<form id='formScore' method='post' action='q_process3.aspx’>";
sHTML += " ";
sHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='Title' name='Title' value= " + title + ">";
sHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='Result' name='Result' value= " + resultstatus + ">";
sHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='ScorePctg' name='ScorePctg' value= " + scorepctg + ">";
sHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='ScorePoints' name='ScorePoints' value= " + scorepoints + ">";
sHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='PassingPctg' name='PassingPctg' value= " + passingpctg + ">";
sHTML += "<input type='hidden' id='PassingPoints' name='PassingPoints' value= " + passingpoints + ">";
sHTML += "<br><input type='submit'><br>";
sHTML += "<form>";

document.getElementById("divEmail").innerHTML = sHTML;
document.getElementById("formScore").submit();
```

When this submits however, the action/url it points to is:
  q_process3.aspx’%3E%20%3Cinput%20type=
So it looks like it is immediately concatenating the 1st input tag onto the the action property of the form element in the string. What am I doing wrong? Or overlooking? I know it's something simple.

Comment: You have a smart quote after your action URL. Is that from your code or just a copy-paste issue?  What happens when you change it to a regular tick quote `'`?

Comment: you are not closing `</form>` tag properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code typo error

```
sHTML += "<form id='formScore' method='post' action='q_process3.aspx’>";
                                                    ^               ^
sHTML += "<form>"; // ought to be </form>
```

Whether there is reason to submit form immediately?

```
document.getElementById("formScore").submit();
```

Comment: That quote discrepancy was it. Thank you. I caught the closing form tag right after I made the post, but it didn't seem to be the problem. Thanks again....

Answer (score 1):

If I take your code and run it in jsFiddle, I get a long, mangled form action.

If I replace your action's ending smart quote with a plain old tick quote (I'm not sure of the correct namings), the form action is set properly.

Change your form tag string to:

```
sHTML += "<form id='formScore' method='post' action='q_process3.aspx'>";
```

That should do it.